# Bot composer - Hero Card - Button to new dialog

Tags: javascript, botframework, bots

I'm trying to set button in my HeroCard as trigger to call another dialog called log_is. My original idea was to parse "log_is" after clicking the button and use value as trigger. But no success. I believe there is much more simple solution.
My code:

```
# herocard
[HeroCard
  title = Login issue
  text = Login issue
  buttons = ${cardActionTemplate("imBack", "Login Issue", "log_is")}

# cardActionTemplate( Type,  Title, Value)
[CardAction
    Type = ${type}
    Title= ${title}
    Value = ${value}
   
]
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Is `log_is` setup as an intent? Are you using LUIS or regex recognizer? If you are putting the response into a property, you could use an ifcondition. But The better option i think is to have a recognizer grab it.